# Is there any physical significance for least norm solution of underdetermined systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

When having an underdetermined system of linear equations (a fat matrix), then, linear algebra is offering an interesting particular solution, which is "least norm", i.e. the shortest. I want to know if this has any meaning in physics, i.e. why would we favor this solution. Practical exemplar problems from physics are appreciated.

PS: I wanted to ask this in physics.stackexchange but I couldn't think of a single appropriate topic tag.

Comment: Least norm enforces a physical "continuity" restriction that the solution we are looking for shouldn't differ greatly from one datapoint to the next. However, this isn't always the best metric to penalize. Some procedures penalize curvature to smoothly connect one point to the next.

Comment: @NinadMunshi What is the name of the solution that penalizes for bad curvature?

Comment: As far as I'm aware it doesn't have one. I worked on it for a research topic a while ago as a way to design an algorithm for neutron spectrum unfolding.

Comment: In general, the norm of a vector can be associated with its inherent energy, so that the least norm solution is in some sense the solution that uses the least energy

Comment: Here is an example of a physical problem that I encountered where least norm solutions are useful: a submarine (a point mass for our purposes) propels itself with jets that point in fixed directions $v_1,\dots,v_n$.  The submarine steers by moderating the force produced by each jet (forces are allowed to be negative). Given an acceleration vector $v$, find the forces that should be assigned to each jet in order to achieve this acceleration while expending minimal power.

Comment: @JohnDeterious "What is the name of the solution that penalizes for bad curvature?" The solution itself might not have a name, but the regularization term in our optimization problem might have a name -- such as Tikhonov regularization or total variation regularization.